# nuget pack raises an Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception

Tags: command-line, nuget, nuget-package

I am having a weird issue with nuget.exe command line tool.

I have a console application that launches a process which executes nuget command line tool.

Here is the output:

```
nuget.exe pack Project.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release 
Attempting to build package from 'Project.csproj'. Packing files from
'C:\Project\bin\Release'.
```

It throws an Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception.

But the way, my process WorkingDirectory is C:\Project, so the file path is ok.

What is weird is that when I use the standard windows command line, cd into the .csproj folder and execute the same command, the nupkg file is being created.

If I do:

```
cd ..
```

and runs:

```
nuget.exe pack Project\Project.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release
```

I am getting the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. exception.

My console application code is:

```
var process = new Process  {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("nuget.exe", 
                                     "pack Project.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release")
                    {
                        WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Project",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    }
};
```

Comment: Any luck with this? My TeamCity is doing this...

Comment: Yes, just posted my answer. Does not exactly solve the issue with nuget.exe but it works and I have been able to build my .nupkg files in my CI correctly.

Comment: I ended up reverting to Nuget 1.6 for the time being...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and my problem was that after an update of an package (and a merge in SVN), the packages.config file still had both versions of the package referenced: the old and the new package. After I deleted the folder with the old package, the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."-error popped up.

So, to solve that error, be sure that your packages.config file only has one version of a package in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this null reference error happens because your packages.config has an entry to the assembly you no longer have.

For example, my packages.config wass like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="H.Common" version="1.0.0.9" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="H.Common" version="1.0.0.10" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="H.Validation" version="3.0.0.50" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

And nuget pack raised an error, as the config had a reference to a ghost assembly.
I removed the line and now the config became like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="H.Common" version="1.0.0.10" targetFramework="net35" />
  <package id="H.Validation" version="3.0.0.50" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

It compiles happy now.